# Sharepoint online API creating folder 500 error

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, document-library, error, folder

I am brand new to the SharePoint API. I am trying to create folders in a customer SharePoint solution.

When I'm posting I get the following 500 error (fiddler):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><m:code>-1, System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException</m:code><m:message xml:lang="da-DK">The given key was not present in the dictionary.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

And this is what I am doing:

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();

            string USER = "xxxxx@xxxxx.com";
            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            string PWD = "xxxxxx";
            PWD.ToList().ForEach(passWord.AppendChar);
            SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(USER, passWord);
            client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
            client.Credentials = credentials;
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json;odata=verbose");
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json;odata=verbose");
            client.BaseAddress = "https://xxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Test/Syra_Test";
            // Get Digest
            string digestUrl = "/_api/contextinfo";
            string digestResult = client.UploadString(digestUrl, "POST");
            JToken dr = JToken.Parse(digestResult);
            string digest = dr["d"]["GetContextWebInformation"]["FormDigestValue"].ToString();

            // So far so good! FormDigest is returned here so I know I have correct credentials
            // Add Digest to next request
            client.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", digest);
            client.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "POST");
            string endpointUri = "/_api/web/folders";
            string payloadString = "{'__metadata':{'type':'SP.Folder'},'ServerRelativeUrl':'/test'}";
            // Fails here!!
            string result = client.UploadString(endpointUri, "POST", payloadString);
            JToken t = JToken.Parse(result);
            Console.WriteLine(t);
```

What am I doing wrong?

It was a url problem. But now im getting a 403 when trying to create, GET works fine.

Comment: before creating a folder, can you retrieve some data from SharePoint first? for example, setn GET equest to `/_api/web` ?

Comment: Yes tried GET all files from location, i get a 200, but not data even though i expect 1 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are passing wrong payload. Make sure you are passing correct server relative URL of your document library where you want to create a folder.

You should pass the payload in below format:

```
{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Folder"
  },
  "ServerRelativeUrl": "/document library relative url/folder name"
}
```

Example `ServerRelativeUrl`:

```
"ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/SPConnect/Shared Documents/folder1"
```

Where `Shared Documents` is document library name (name in library URL) & `folder1` is the name of folder I want to create inside document library.

**Source**: [Working with folders by using REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-folders-by-using-rest)

---

**Example code for reference - using REST API in JavaScript**:

```
    function createFolderWithPayload() {
        var folderEndpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/folders";
        var folderPayload = {
            "__metadata": {
                "type": "SP.Folder"
            },
            "ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/SPConnect/Shared Documents/folder1"
        };
        
        $.ajax({
            url: folderEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(folderPayload),
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Folder created successfully");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: tried changing relative url, still getting 500 key missing error. Here's my fiddler.: POST https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/web/folders HTTP/1.1
X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED: f
X-RequestDigest: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
X-HTTP-Method: POST
Cookie: SPOIDCRL=xxxxxxxxx
Authorization: 
Host: xxxxxx.sharepoint.com
Content-Length: 93
Expect: 100-continue

{'__metadata': {'type':'SP.Folder'},'ServerRelativeUrl': '/sites/Test/Shared Documents/test'}

Answer (score 0):

In my case the accepted solution did not work, neither by using the complete server relative URL.
I solved by recording in chrome the http requests sent while creating a folder from the web GUI. I saw that the request that the browser was sending to create the folder was the following

```
POST https://{site_url}/_api/web/folders/AddUsingPath(DecodedUrl='{server_relative_url_of_new_folder}',overwrite='false')
```

Hope it will help anyone not finding the accepted solution to work!